# Laravel debug bar session message not displayed

Tags: laravel, phpdebugbar

Output message works fine but **debugbar** session doesn't have them

```
if (empty($item)) {
  return back()
    ->withErrors(['msg' => "post id => {$id} not found"])
    ->withInput();
}
```

[debugbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me5xT.png)

- `laravel 5.8`
- `debugbar 7.3.1`

Comment: got the same in laravel 8, debugbar 3.5.5, xampp